# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DecisionTreeClassifier & TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am working on a machine learning problem using jupyter notebook.

1. Earlier 'joblib' was not importing from sklearn.externals so I just wrote the code 'import joblib' as you can see in the code line 3. But i don't know why it is displaying this two errors, is the joblib package isn't loading the model or something? If anyone can figure this out please help.
   This is the code:

   ```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    import joblib

    # music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
    # X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
    # y = music_data['genre']

    # model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    # model.fit(X, y)

    model = joblib.load(model, 'music-recommender.joblib')
    predictions = model.predict([[21, 1]])
    predictions
   ```

It is giving the error as follows:

```
    TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-12-454f717d8a19> in <module>
    10 # model.fit(X, y)
    11 
    ---> 12 model = joblib.load(model, 'music-recommender.joblib')
    13 predictions = model.predict([[21, 1]])
    14 predictions

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    575             obj = _unpickle(fobj)
    576     else:
  ---> 577          with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    578             with _read_fileobject(f, filename, mmap_mode) as fobj:
    579                 if isinstance(fobj, str):

   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DecisionTreeClassifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
model = joblib.load(model, 'filename.joblib')
```

you should type:

```
model = joblib.load('filename.joblib')
```

You can see that [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html).